# Eureka client getting registered with unknown urls

Tags: spring-boot, docker, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

When I run the `Eureka` server, `zuul` gateway and other services on localhost, they are registered as below and work as intended.

```
Application AMIs    Availability Zones  Status
AUTH-SERVICE    n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - localhost:auth-service:9100
IDOT-GATEWAY    n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - localhost:idot-gateway:8762
MAIN-SERVICE    n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - localhost:main-service:8200
```

However If i deploy the same using `docker` images on `OCP` as I understand they need to connect through service-name. So I give the same. My services are named as idot-eurekaserver, idot-gateway, idot-auth

Like property for gateway

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://idot-eurekaserver:8761/eureka
```

However now when I check in `Eureka` UI urls are self generated and requests are failing unable to reach that url, like `gateway` now tries to reach `auth-service` at `idot-auth-3-t7454` and fails unable to resolve.

```
Instances currently registered with Eureka

Application AMIs    Availability Zones  Status
AUTH-SERVICE    n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - idot-auth-3-t7454:auth-service:9100
IDOT-GATEWAY    n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - idot-gateway-2-jyps1:idot-gateway:8762
```

Why are these urls being generated, instead of `idot-auth:auth-service:9100`, how can I resolve the same?

FYI - the auto url generated works on docker images locally. It's just not working on `OCP` when each service is a different pod and they are grouped together as a single container.

Answer (score 0):

Using below property in all clients helped, now the pods are able to talk to each other.

```
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```